# multithread exception handling free resources

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to handle all exceptions generated in a multithreaded problem so as to eliminate memory leaks, interrupted or execution exceptions (I do not want to propagate them) and similar. In the event that I interrupt a thread (`Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`), is `shutdownNow()` redundant in the `finally` below?

```
ThreadPoolExecutor service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(coreSize, maxSize);

// do stuff

try {               
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();

    for (Item item : items) {
        // processing logic
        Runnable myTask = new MyTask();
        futures.add(service.submit(myTask));
    }

    for (Future<?> f : futures) {
        f.get();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // todo
} finally {
    service.shutdown();
    try {
        service.awaitTermination(duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // todo
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } finally {
        if (!service.isTerminated()) {
            service.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shutdownNow` will behave the same way as `shutdown` if a `MyTask` *ignore any interruptions*. In this case, yes, `shutdownNow` is redundant.

On the other hand, if *the interruption can affect* a `MyTask`, then `shutdownNow` is necessary for stopping working threads.

Answer (score 1):

It is redundant only when:

- All running tasks are not interruptable.
- And there is no cached task in the blocking queue.

Call [`shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) will make the executor not accept new tasks, but the tasks cached in the blocking queue will still be executed.

Call [`shutdownNow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()) will

- `interrupt` all tasks that are running
- cancel all tasks in the queue